# Update a combo box based on another combo box's selection

Tags: vba, outlook

In VB for applications I have this code:

```
Private Sub cc_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    cc.AddItem "op1"
    cc.AddItem "op2"
    cc.AddItem "op3"
    cc.AddItem "op4"

End Sub
```

The above works.

I would like to further develop this so when you click "op1" you get associated options, this is the code I have so far;

```
Private Sub combo2_Change()
    If cc = "op1" Then
    Me.combo2.RowSourceType = "Value List"
    Me.combo2.RowSource = "a; b; c"
    Else
    Me.combo2.RowSourceType = "Value List"
    Me.combo2.RowSource = "default"
    End If
End Sub
```

I have only listed "op1" as it would be transferable. Please can you help me, when I select "op1" I don't get the values "a" "b" or "c"

Answer (score 0):

If I got it correctly, you need to write the code for the event of changing the first combo box (cc) inside its change event. Try doing the following:

```
Private Sub cc_Change()
    If cc = "op1" Then
        Me.combo2.RowSourceType = "Value List"
        Me.combo2.RowSource = "a; b; c"
    Else
        Me.combo2.RowSourceType = "Value List"
        Me.combo2.RowSource = "default"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Within the private sub of `cc_Change()`
Use this:

```
If cc = "op1" Then
        combo2.AddItem "a"
Else
        combo2.AddItem "default"
End If
```